# Vim: replace all non letter non digit and non '-' char from line

Tags: regex, vim

I recently start use `vim` and spent some try to solve that problem.
So I have a string, for example `"I'm 20 years old - and you?"` I need to get from this `'I_m_20_years_old_-_and_you_'`

In java it is seems pretty straightforward smth like this `[^a-Z0-9\-]+`, but I can't get work similar regex in Vim
I've tried `:26s/\(\W\)/_/g` but it is remove all '-' as well.
How to add in regex 'and not -' ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `-` is not a word character. Use the same regex `[^a-Z0-9-]+`

Comment: @Toto , yes, I know that, that why I thougth use 'and not -' combination.
`:26s/[^a-Z0-9-]+/_/g` does not work It gives errors E944, E476

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your `:26s/[^a-Z0-9-]+/_/g` attempt is `a-Z`, which is not a valid range. It should be `a-zA-Z`.

(`A-z` would "work", but if you look at the [ASCII table](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html), it also includes `` [\]^_` ``, not just letters.)

The next problem is that `+` is not a regex meta-character in vim (at least, not by default). `[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+` would look for a non-alphanumeric non-`-` character followed by a literal `+`. It needs to be `\+` instead.

That gives us `s/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]\+/_/g`, which works.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://vimregex.com/ it should be like this

```
s/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]\+/_/g
```

Comment: ... someone just downvoted and then un-downvoted the other two answers. Was that you?

Comment: Nah same happened to me as well I was -1 earlier then I'm 0 now

Comment: No, that was me. I had downvoted your answer because it was the only one with non-working code. I removed the downvote when you fixed it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Escape `-` and `+`:

```
:s/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]\+/_/g
```